# Executable not visible when run with sudo

Tags: sudo, executable

Platform:  `Ubuntu 10.04` VM running out of `VirtualBox`

File details:

```
-rwxr-x---  1 myuser myuser  123 2013-10-31 16:10 myscript.sh
```

The executable is visible in the directory:

```
>type myscript.sh
myscript.sh is ./myscript.sh
```

I do have . in the path:

```
>echo $PATH
.:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Running it without `sudo` works fine:

```
>myscript.sh
```

but not with sudo:

```
>sudo myscript.sh
sudo: myscript.sh: command not found
```

Why?

Comment: PATH is not inherited in sudo. Doing so would be a security flaw since someone might stick something unsafe in PATH such as `.`.

Answer (score 4):

> Sudo resets PATH, along with many other environment variables, for security reasons. It doesn't matter what is set in /etc/profile, unless you run sudo -i.
>
> The sudo manual page, under SECURITY NOTES, gives an insight about the security implications, along with the options you have to fiddle in your /etc/sudoers file to modify these restrictions, after you understand the implications of doing so."

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/11899/how-to-override-a-path-environment-variable-in-sudo